# Generate Plain Text Fields Based on Chosen Spinner Value?

Tags: java, android, xml

I'm currently working on creating an app in android studio. The problem I am facing is generating a number of "plain text" objects based on the number chosen in a spinner. I have included layout of the activity below.

[layout of activity can be seen here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YmLzJ.png)

Once the "number of people" are picked, then the area to enter the peoples names will be generated based on that. Max number of people will be 4.

Any help on how to do this would be much appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would suggest using an `OnItemSelectedListener()` on your spinner along with setting the `setVisibility()` of your 'person' fields.

This code will assume your minimum people to be 1.  Each time a new value is selected from the spinner the fields will appear or disappear.  Using `GONE` for visibility will hide the field but also remove the space used by it. Use `INVISIBLE` if you want to keep the space.

Also don't bother setting the visibility in the xml layout code as this can cause issues.

```
    person1 = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.person1);
    person2 = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.person2);
    person3 = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.person3);
    person4 = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.person4);

    list = new ArrayList<String>();

    list.add("1");
    list.add("2");
    list.add("3");
    list.add("4");

    spinner = (Spinner)findViewById(R.id.spinner);

    ArrayAdapter<String> adapter= new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, list);

    adapter.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);

    spinner.setAdapter(adapter);

    spinner.setOnItemSelectedListener(new AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener()
    {
        @Override
        public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id)
        {
            spinnerValue = parent.getItemAtPosition(position).toString();

            int value = Integer.parseInt(spinnerValue);

            // Simpler logic for the visibility of the 'people' - kudos to RobCo for pointing this out//
            person1.setVisibility(value>=1? view.VISIBLE:View.GONE);
            person2.setVisibility(value>=2? view.VISIBLE:View.GONE);
            person3.setVisibility(value>=3? view.VISIBLE:View.GONE);
            person4.setVisibility(value>=4? view.VISIBLE:View.GONE);

          /*
            if (value == 1)
            {
                person1.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                person2.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                person3.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                person4.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            }
            else if (value == 2)
            {
                person1.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                person2.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                person3.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                person4.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            }
            else if (value == 3)
            {
                person1.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                person2.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                person3.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                person4.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            }
            else
            {
                person1.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                person2.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                person3.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                person4.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            }
          */

        }

        @Override
        public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> parent)
        {

        }
    });
```

Good luck.

Comment: Good idea, apart from the large if-else statements which have a lot of repetition. You could do `person1.setVisibility(value >= 1 ?
 View.VISIBLE : View.GONE);` for each view once.

Comment: I haven't tried this but yes if it works it could cut down on the `if` loops ... although the `if else` loops are simply checking an integer value so I'm not sure about the performance impact on the app?

Comment: Performance won't be the issue. It's about readability and maintainability. If you want to increase the max amount of rows to say, 10, you now have to add close to 100 lines, instead of just 6.

Comment: ah yes that is true ... i didn't think of it those terms ... good call :)

Comment: i've updated my answer with this included. Honestly this is a function that i hadn't come across myself :) will definitely be useful . Cheers @RobCo

Answer (score 0):

You simply do it by setting the visibility of all the 4 EditTexts as false and set a listener to the spinner. And inside the listener add if else statement and depending upon the selection you can set the visibility on for the EditText fields.